# Add local python module to Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a spark cluster which I code against using Jupyter notebooks this all works really fine so far. But now I would like to add a local module (lets call it `hello.py`) which is located on my local file system at `/var/lib/mymodules/hello.py`

I tried `sc.addPyFile("/var/lib/mymodules/hello.py")` but it was always complaining that it cannot find the file

Next I tried `sc.addPyFile("file:///var/lib/mymodules/hello.py")`

according to the official documentation, local files should by supported by addPyFile but I could not get it to work

what would be the correct syntax to use here

Comment: Do you see the file if you execute cell with content `!ls -l /var/lib/mymodules/hello.py`?

Comment: yes, the file exists

Comment: Can you paste the whole stacktrace?